# Getting thumbnail AND normal size from image

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, magento-1, image

I am using these two functions to get two different sizes of the same image (thumbnail and normal):

```
$thumb = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(100, 100);
$big = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile());
```

But, when I want to call `$thumb` with an echo, it shows the `$big` value. If I turn `$thumb` and `$big` around, it does show the `$thumb` value, but not the `$big` value.

How do I sove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to turn those into strings in order to be able to use them properly because the helper returns itself by default:

```
$thumb = (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(100, 100);
$big = (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile());
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code it helped me might help you

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
echo $thumb = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(100, 100);
echo $big = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail');
```